# DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S. Unable to set spring.data.cassandra.request.timeout property?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

When starting my application the keyspace is always created and possibly one or two tables before the PT2S error message . Somehow the spring.data.cassandra.request.timeout property is not honored, or maybe there is something wrong with my configuration? The "DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer" bean does not make any difference.

pom.xml

```
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
<version>Hoxton.SR9</version>
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
<spring.framework.version>5.3.1</spring.framework.version>
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      port: 9042
      keyspace-name: abc
      contact-points: localhost
      local-datacenter: datacenter1
      replication-factor: 1
      request:
        timeout: 15s
      connection:
        init-query-timeout: 15s
```

CassandraConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "a.b.c.repository")
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contactpoints}")
    .
    .
    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keyspace;
    }
    @Override protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }
    @Override protected int getPort() {
        return port;
    }
    @Override
    protected String getLocalDataCenter() {
        return datacenter;
    }
   @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.NONE;
    }
    @Override
    protected List<CreateKeyspaceSpecification> getKeyspaceCreations() {
        return Collections.singletonList(CreateKeyspaceSpecification.createKeyspace(getKeyspaceName())
                .ifNotExists()
                .with(KeyspaceOption.DURABLE_WRITES, true)
                .withNetworkReplication(DataCenterReplication.of(getLocalDataCenter(), getReplicationFactor())));
    }
    @Override
    protected KeyspacePopulator keyspacePopulator() {
        ResourceKeyspacePopulator keyspacePopulate = new ResourceKeyspacePopulator();
        keyspacePopulate.addScript(new ClassPathResource("table-schema.cql"));
        return keyspacePopulate;
    }
    private long getReplicationFactor() {
        return replicationFactor;
    }
    //@Bean
    //public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer driverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer() {
        //return loaderBuilder -> loaderBuilder
                //.withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                //.withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_INIT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(15));
    //}

}
```

Trimmed error log

```
BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSessionFactory' 
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute CQL script statement #2 of class path resource [table-schema.cql]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable...

Caused by: org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute CQL script statement #2 of class path resource [table-schema.cql]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytanble... nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.init.ScriptUtils.executeCqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:555) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.session.init.ResourceKeyspacePopulator.populate
    
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: Query timed out after PT2S
at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We had a similar problem and tried your exact steps first.
The [driver examples code](https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/spring-k8s-cassandra-microservices/blob/master/microservice-spring-data/src/main/java/com/datastax/examples/SpringDataCassandraConfiguration.java) than stirred us in the right direction.
We have a custom cassandra config with excluded auto config:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {CassandraAutoConfiguration.class,CassandraDataAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Running spring-boot-starter-parent version 2.3.0.RELEASE.

CassandraConfig:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.model.cassandra"})
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

@Override
protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() {
    return new SessionBuilderConfigurer() {
        @Override
        public CqlSessionBuilder configure(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
            return cqlSessionBuilder
                    .withConfigLoader(DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder().withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofMillis(15000)).build());
        }
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Why is it not working for me. I removed all the auto configs as you said. But still getting the timeout error all the time, irrespective of what time I set on 'DriverConfigLoader'. I stuck on this for 2 days and still not able to fix that. I am using spring boot 2.4.4 and java driver 4.9 (managed)

Comment: Why do you need to exclude the auto-configuration for this? If you extends fro the parent cassandra configuration, you are already doing a full user-configuration. None of the customizers of Spring Boot are going to be used, because the auto-configuration does not apply anyway. You should rather let Spring Boot do its things and create an issue if there is something that it doesn't support.

Comment: I did all the possible things that I should do. Once I removed and did complete user configuration I still faced that. Then I removed everything and let spring boot do things for myself but still faced the same.  The solution here given looks good to me that do not work at all. I have posted this question here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67217692/spring-cassandra-time-out-query-select-from-system-schema-tables-timed-out-a