# Spring Cassandra time out query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables' timed out after PT2S

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring Boot `2.4.4` and Spring Data Cassandra dependency to connect to the Cassandra database. During the application startup, I am getting a DriverTimeout error (I am using VPN).

I have gone through all the Stack Overflow questions similar to this and none of them worked for me. I have cross-posted the same question on the Spring Boot [official page here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24189).

I used below configuration properties below -

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=xxxxxx
spring.data.cassandra.username=xxxx
spring.data.cassandra.password=xxxxx
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=xxxx
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
spring.data.cassandra.schema-action=NONE
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=mydc
spring.data.cassandra.connection.connect-timeout=PT10S
spring.data.cassandra.connection.init-query-timeout=PT20S
spring.data.cassandra.request.timeout=PT10S
```

I also added DataStax properties in the application.properties to check if they can be picked up from there or not.

```
datastax-java-driver.basic.request.timeout = 10 seconds
datastax-java-driver.advanced.connection.init-query-timeout = 10 seconds
datastax-java-driver.advanced.control-connection.timeout = 10 seconds
```

Below is the configuration I used as suggested in the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072999/drivertimeoutexception-query-timed-out-after-pt2s-unable-to-set-spring-data-ca) -

```
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig {
    @Bean
        DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer cassandraDriverCustomizer() {
            return (builder) -> builder.withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONTROL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT,
                    Duration.ofSeconds(30));
        }
}
```

But I still get the same error

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables' timed out after PT2S
```

I also tried different approached like creating custom CqlSessionFactoryBean and provide all the DataStax properties programmatically to override -

```
@EnableCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration { 

    @Bean(name = "session")
        @Primary
        public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
            CqlSessionFactoryBean factory = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
            factory.setUsername(userName);
            factory.setPassword(password);
            factory.setPort(port);
            factory.setKeyspaceName(keyspaceName);
            factory.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
            factory.setLocalDatacenter(dataCenter);
            factory.setSessionBuilderConfigurer(getSessionBuilderConfigurer()); // my session builder configurer 
            return factory;
        }
    // And provided my own SessionBuilder Configurer like below
    
    protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() {
        return new SessionBuilderConfigurer() {
    
            @Override
            public CqlSessionBuilder configure(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
                ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder config = DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_INIT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                        .withBoolean(DefaultDriverOption.RECONNECT_ON_INIT, true)
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONTROL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
                return cqlSessionBuilder.withAuthCredentials(userName, password).withConfigLoader(config.build());
            }
        };
      }
}
```

It didn't work same error. Also, I excluded the Cassandra auto-configuration classes like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072999/drivertimeoutexception-query-timed-out-after-pt2s-unable-to-set-spring-data-ca) on StackOverflow

I also tried to customize custom session builder like below to see if that can work -

```
@Bean
public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer cqlSessionBuilderCustomizer() {
        return cqlSessionBuilder -> cqlSessionBuilder.withAuthCredentials(userName, password)
                .withConfigLoader(DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofMillis(15000))
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_INIT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                        .withBoolean(DefaultDriverOption.RECONNECT_ON_INIT, true)
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                        .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONTROL_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(20)).build());
    }
```

Still no luck.

Not only that I also added the `application.conf` file as [DataStax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/core/configuration/) suggested putting that on the classpath, even though that file is getting parsed (after making the syntactical mistake I got to know that it is being read). It didn't work.

application.conf-

```
datastax-java-driver {
 basic.request.timeout = 10 seconds
 advanced.connection.init-query-timeout = 10 seconds
 advanced.control-connection.timeout = 10 seconds
}
```

I also switched my Spring Boot version to `2.5.0.M3` to see property files works it does not. I have pushed my project to [my GitHub account](https://github.com/rajeevshukla/spring-cassandra-configuration/tree/master/spring-cassandra-testing).

### Update

As per the comment, I am pasting my whole stack trace.  Also, this does not happen all the time sometimes it works sometimes it does not. I need to override the timeout from PT2S to PT10S or something.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraConverter' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/CassandraConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'cassandraConverter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables' timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:895) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringCassandraTestingApplication.main(SpringCassandraTestingApplication.java:13) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.convert.CassandraConverter]: Factory method 'cassandraConverter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables' timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cassandraSession' defined in class path resource [com/example/demo/CassandraConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables' timed out after PT2S
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1796) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:227) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1174) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:422) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:352) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractSessionConfiguration.requireBeanOfType(AbstractSessionConfiguration.java:100) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractSessionConfiguration.getRequiredSession(AbstractSessionConfiguration.java:200) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.AbstractCassandraConfiguration.cassandraConverter(AbstractCassandraConfiguration.java:73) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cec229ff.CGLIB$cassandraConverter$12(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.demo.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cec229ff$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$faa9c2c1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:331) ~[spring-context-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.CassandraConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$cec229ff.cassandraConverter(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_275]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException: query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables' timed out after PT2S
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.DriverTimeoutException.copy(DriverTimeoutException.java:34) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.internal.core.util.concurrent.CompletableFutures.getUninterruptibly(CompletableFutures.java:149) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.session.Session.refreshSchema(Session.java:140) ~[java-driver-core-4.6.1.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.cassandra.config.CqlSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(CqlSessionFactoryBean.java:437) ~[spring-data-cassandra-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar:3.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 43 common frames omitted
```

Comment: You configured `spring.data.cassandra.connection.init-query-timeout=PT20S` but the error message mentions `PT2S`. Is this a typo? Did you rule out network issues (i.e. check connectivity with `nc` or similar)? I would check `netstat -nt` output while the app is running, before the time out occurs.

Comment: What's the complete stack trace of the timeout? It's not clear from the error message when the timeout is occurring.

Comment: It may be a side-effect of you trying to solve your problem, but in its current form your project is mostly configuring Cassandra itself. This means that Spring Boot's auto-configuration has largely backed off. As a result any `spring.data.cassandra.*` properties that you have set won't have any effect unless you're using them in your own code.

Comment: Are you able to connect to Cassandra from the machine you are running your code on?

Comment: @jny Yes. I am able connect.

Comment: @TasosP. This is why I asked this question PT20S should override PT2S. but it is not doing that. There is no typo.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I am updating the question with a complete stack trace soon.
Also, regarding your second comment, I have done both ways, I used the entire autoconfiguration first and see if that property gets overridden or not but it has no effect in either way, custom and in autoconfiguration.

Comment: How stuck are you on Spring Data Cassandra?  It's been my experience that it sometimes does some weird things behind the scenes.  I'd recommend using the DataStax Java driver.

Comment: Spring-data-Cassandra is using DataStax 4.9 at the backend. Yes, it is weird to see that I am stuck on such a silly issue. It is driving me crazy. :-D.

Comment: @Rajeev I am facing the exact same issue. Wanted to check if you tried directly using datastax Java driver 4.5+ & if yes did it work for you ?

Comment: @AbhishekSharmaM, I answered this question, how I fixed it today. Great relief. ! Shhhh

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I am answering my own question here to make this complete and let others know how I fixed this particular problem.

I am using Spring Boot 2.4.5. and I started facing this timeout issue when I upgraded to version 2.3+ onwards.

Based on my experience with this issue, below is what I found.

Irrespective of whatever timeout you provide in the `application.properties` or `application.conf` ([DataStax notion](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.6/manual/core/configuration/)), They all somehow getting overridden by the spring boot or maybe selecting the default value from the DataStax driver.

Even there is an issue created on the Spring Boot official project to handle this problem. Check [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/24189). Which got fixed later in the 2.5.0.M1 version.

My problem got fixed when I passed this as a VM argument.

```
 $java -Ddatastax-java-driver.basic.request.timeout="15 seconds" application.jar
```

I passed other params as well like `advanced.control-connection.timeout` as I was suggested to use on a different forum but that didn't work for me.  Check reference manual [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.4/manual/core/configuration/reference/) for other config params.

I am getting this error at my local only so I passed this in the Eclipse VM argument and then I didn't see that error any more.

Also if I reduce this time to 7-8 seconds sometimes I see that error again `PT2S`. Seems like that exception message is hardcoded somewhere irrespective of whatever timeout value you pass. (That is my observation).

[image]

**Update: Solution 2 - Which I figured out later and I see many of the people have answered that too**
The actual key that DataStax provides is given below and this works.

```
 @Bean
    public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer defaultProfile(){
        return builder -> builder.withString(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, "3 seconds").build();
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is an expanded answer in addition to the person who provided the right answer.

Increase the METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT because that query stated in the problem belongs to the METADATA_SCHEMA, which was not explicit.

```
@Override
    protected SessionBuilderConfigurer getSessionBuilderConfigurer() {
        return new SessionBuilderConfigurer() {

            @Override
            public CqlSessionBuilder configure(CqlSessionBuilder cqlSessionBuilder) {
                logger.info("Configuring CqlSession Builder");
                return cqlSessionBuilder
                        .withConfigLoader(DriverConfigLoader.programmaticBuilder()
                                // Resolves the timeout query 'SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables' timed out after PT2S
                                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofMillis(60000))
                                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.CONNECTION_INIT_QUERY_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofMillis(60000))
                                .withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofMillis(15000))
                                .build());
            }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The `DriverTimeoutException` gets thrown when the driver doesn't get a reply from the coordinator node. It uses the basic request timeout default of 2 seconds:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic.request {
    timeout = 2 seconds
```

The fact that the timeout is 2 seconds means that none of your overrides are getting picked up but I haven't quite figured out why yet.

More importantly, it's a different error to a read or write timeout exception which occur when not enough replicas responded to satisfy the required consistency level -- in either of these cases, the coordinator replies back to the driver with the exception.

In my experience, a `DriverTimeoutException` is caused by (a) unresponsive nodes, and/or (b) overloaded coordinator.

If the app is running an expensive query, that could be the reason that coordinator doesn't respond back in time. In this case, your overrides not working is not the problem you need to solve because in Cassandra terms, 2 seconds is an eternity for app requests  -- you need to make sure you're not overloading your cluster and that's the problem you need to solve. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, Erick, I have gone through all the documentation and suggestions you gave already applied. But the thing is I don't have control over the Cassandra node to make it responsive, In order to get this working, I must need to increase the request timeout. I don't have any other option. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @Rajeev , Erick is correct.  Nothing good ever comes from increasing the timeouts.

Comment: @Aaron, Yes Indeed. I have no doubt about that, But I use a VPN on my local laptop, it would happen many times for me and my team. Also, when load increase on our application we scale our application to n number of pods there if Cassandra is busy serving lots of requests to already running pods,  then there is the possibility that the new pod startup may fail if Cassandra is not able to respond withing 2s, I am trying to increase at least 5s to avoid such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

Try to create a bean as below and try:

```
  @Bean
    public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer defaultProfile(){
        return builder -> builder.withString(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, "3 seconds").build();
    }
```

or

```
@Bean
    public DriverConfigLoaderBuilderCustomizer defaultProfile(){
        return builder -> builder.withInt(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, 3000).build();
    }
```

Comment: Please take a moment to learn the code formatting tools here - we use Markdown. Online help is available in the editor.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this in the **session builder configurer**:

```java
withDuration(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_REQUEST_TIMEOUT, Duration.ofSeconds(XX))
```

Answer (score 0):

So I see two possibilities here.

1. The most intriguing part of this question...

...is the `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT * FROM system_schema.tables
```

The keyspace definition of `system_schema` is this:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE system_schema WITH replication = {'class': 'LocalStrategy'}
```

Was this changed to be Simple or NetworkTopology?  If so, that could be causing the timeouts, specifically.

2. The `system_schema` keyspace is new to newer versions of Cassandra (2.2+, I think).  Is it possible you're using an older version?

Basically, make sure the `system_schema` is set with its appropriate, default replication.  Also, make sure to use a version of Spring Data Cassandra that is known to work with your version of Cassandra.

Also, I'd recommend trying this *without* Spring Data Cassandra.  I'm curious to see if there's any difference between that and just using the pure DS Java Driver.

Comment: I am using Cassandra 3.11. If I attempt to restart the application it fails 7 times out of 10 at the startup only. Once it is connected then things are fine. I am trying to see if I can avoide that startup failure.

Comment: @Rajeev Edit made.  Maybe try this without Spring Data Cassandra, and see if the results are any different?

Comment: Okay, will try as you said. Thanks, Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

Increasing request timeout does solve the problem.

But the main reason we got timeout is the default value of "DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_ENABLED" is true

By override the value to false will boost up the speed.

Example on kotlin as below :

```
class CassandraConfiguration(
private val cassandraProperties: CassandraProperties,
) : AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration() {

...
...

override fun getDriverConfigLoaderBuilderConfigurer(): DriverConfigLoaderBuilderConfigurer? {
        return DriverConfigLoaderBuilderConfigurer{ builder: ProgrammaticDriverConfigLoaderBuilder ->
            builder
                .withString(DefaultDriverOption.METADATA_SCHEMA_ENABLED, "false")
                .build()
        }
    }
    
}
```